# Rust slower than Python at parsing files

Tags: performance, rust

I was hoping to use Rust to speed up some of the text processing scrips that are currently written in Python.

In order to test the performance of the two languages, I decided to test them on a very simple task:

- Read in a file from `STDIN`, line by line.
- If the line starts with `>`, save the line to a `headers.txt` file.
- Otherwise, save the line to a `sequences.txt` file.

For this test, I am using a fasta file with 10 million lines, which looks as follows:

```
$ head uniparc_active-head.fasta
>UPI0000000001 status=active
MGAAASIQTTVNTLSERISSKLEQEANASAQTKCDIEIGNFYIRQNHGCNLTVKNMCSAD
ADAQLDAVLSAATETYSGLTPEQKAYVPAMFTAALNIQTSVNTVVRDFENYVKQTCNSSA
VVDNKLKIQNVIIDECYGAPGSPTNLEFINTGSSKGNCAIKALMQLTTKATTQIAPKQVA
GTGVQFYMIVIGVIILAALFMYYAKRMLFTSTNDKIKLILANKENVHWTTYMDTFFRTSP
MVIATTDMQN
>UPI0000000002 status=active
MMTPENDEEQTSVFSATVYGDKIQGKNKRKRVIGLCIRISMVISLLSMITMSAFLIVRLN
QCMSANEAAITDAAVAVAAASSTHRKVASSTTQYDHKESCNGLYYQGSCYILHSDYQLFS
DAKANCTAESSTLPNKSDVLITWLIDYVEDTWGSDGNPITKTTSDYQDSDVSQEVRKYFC
```

Here is my Python script:

```py
import fileinput

with open('headers.txt', 'w') as hof, \
        open('sequences.txt', 'w') as sof:
    for line in fileinput.input():
        if line[0] == '>':
            hof.write(line)
        else:
            sof.write(line)
```

and my Rust script (which I compile in `cargo build --release`):

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut headers = File::create("headers.txt").unwrap();
    let mut sequences = File::create("sequences.txt").unwrap();

    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        match &line[..1] {
            ">" => writeln!(headers, "{}", line).unwrap(),
            _ => writeln!(sequences, "{}", line).unwrap(),
        }
    }
}
```

Running some benchmarks:

Python 2.7

```
$ time bash -c 'cat uniparc_active-head.fasta | python2 src/main.py'
real    0m11.704s
user    0m6.996s
sys     0m1.100s
```

Python 3.5

```
$ time bash -c 'cat uniparc_active-head.fasta | python3 src/main.py'
real    0m16.788s
user    0m12.508s
sys     0m1.576s
```

PyPy 5.3.1

```
$ time bash -c 'cat uniparc_active-head.fasta | pypy src/main.py'
real    0m6.526s
user    0m1.536s
sys     0m0.884s
```

Rust 1.14.0

```
$ cargo build --release
$ time bash -c 'cat uniparc_active-head.fasta | target/release/parse_text'
real    0m17.493s
user    0m2.728s
sys     0m15.408s
```

So Rust is ~3x slower than PyPy, and even slower than Python 3.

Can anyone shine some light on this? Did I make a mistake in the Rust code? If not, should I stick to Python / PyPy for processing text files, or is there another language that would be better for the job?

Comment: Oddly, I came upon a very similar situation just a few days ago - I rewrote a text parser in Julia, and the original Python version is 3x faster.

Comment: Your Rust program isn't using a buffered writer. Try replacing your `File::create(...).unwrap()` calls with `io::BufWriter::new(File::create(...).unwrap())`.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 yup, thanks! I had a feeling I was missing something basic.

Comment: How much of an improvement did that produce?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Now it's a bit faster than PyPy. Both are pretty much IO limited at this point, so it's not a good benchmark.

Comment: I would actually bet that it is not IO limited. It's probably bad form to link to an HN comment, but I wrote it recently and it's got lots of details relevant to this question that might help you speed it up even more! https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13268051 (The trick is to remove allocation and perhaps even UTF-8 validation.)

Comment: @BurntSushi5 that's a very interesting post, thanks for writing and sharing! I tried rewriting my code using `... let mut line = vec![]; while rdr.read_until(b'\n', &mut line)? > 0 {...`, but the performance was about the same (it fluctuates too much for me to tell for sure). I could still be missing some optimizations though.

Comment: Interesting. I am kind of surprised, but it's possible! Next step would be to start looking at profiles. Big difference between my HN comment and your code is that you're writing data somewhere where as I was just counting. That could be the normalizer. (Which would mean your original comment about IO being the limiter would be right!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested by @BurntSushi5, replacing

```
let mut headers = File::create("headers.txt").unwrap();
let mut sequences = File::create("sequences.txt").unwrap();
```

with

```
let mut headers = io::BufWriter::new(File::create("headers.txt").unwrap());
let mut sequences = io::BufWriter::new(File::create("sequences.txt").unwrap());
```

Brought the speed up to what I expected:

```
$ time bash -c 'cat uniparc_active-head.fasta | target/release/parse_text'
real    0m5.645s
user    0m1.396s
sys     0m0.804s
```